# Redmine: How to get a value which is saved in mysql database, through a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine-plugins

I need a value that I can read in the init.rb and also change it through the plugin settings on Redmine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNPgw.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nMAy.png

Here is my init.rb from the plugin:

```ruby
require 'redmine'

Redmine::Plugin.register :redmine_embedded_video do
 name 'Redmine Embedded Video'
 author 'Nikolay Kotlyarov, PhobosK, Jan Pilz'
 description 'Embeds attachment videos, video URLs or Youtube videos. Usage (as macro): video(ID|URL|YOUTUBE_URL). Updated to JW Player 6.2.3115, SWFObject removed'
 url 'http://www.redmine.org/issues/5171'
 version '0.0.3.1'

 #Hier ist die plugin configuration:
 settings :default => {'empty' => true}, :partial => 'settings/video_settings'

end
```

```ruby
Redmine::WikiFormatting::Macros.register do
   desc "Wiki video embedding"

    macro :video do |o, args|
        @ratio = args[1] if args[1]
        @ratio ||= "16:9"
        @num ||= 0
        @num = @num + 1
        attachment = o.attachments.find_by_filename(args[0]) if o.respond_to?('attachments')

        if attachment
            file_url = url_for(:only_path => false, :controller => 'attachments', :action => 'download', :id => attachment, :filename => attachment.filename)
        else
            file_url = args[0].gsub(/<.*?>/, '').gsub(/&lt;.*&gt;/,'')
        end
out = <<END
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{ActionController::Base.relative_url_root}/plugin_assets/redmine_embedded_video/jwplayer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer.key="HERE IS WHERE I NEED THE VALUE 'TEST1'";
</script>

<div id="video_#{@num}">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("video_#{@num}").setup({
        file: "#{file_url}",
        image: 'images/video_dummy.jpg',      
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "#{@ratio}"
    });
</script>
END

    out.html_safe
  end
```

jwplayer.key: Is where I need the value 'TEST1'

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `jwplayer.key = <%= Setting.where("name = plugin_redmine_embedded_video").value[5..-1] %>`  :p

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer... the value is cached automatically and saved as a local variable, so I could just get it.

```html
@key = Setting['plugin_redmine_embedded_video']['key']

out = <<END
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{ActionController::Base.relative_url_root}/plugin_assets/redmine_embedded_video/jwplayer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="#{@key}";</script> <!--HERE COMES THE VARIABLE-->

<div id="video_#{@num}">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("video_#{@num}").setup({
        file: "#{file_url}",
        image: 'images/video_dummy.jpg',
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "#{@ratio}"
    });
</script>
END

    out.html_safe
  end
end
```